# Does a PHP MySQL Transaction make only one call to the server?

Tags: php, mysql

When using PHP and MySQL Transaction - as in the example below.

```
$db->beginTransaction();

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $db->query('first query');
    $db->query('second query');
    $db->query('third query');

$db->commit();
```

**Does this make only 1 call to the server?**

**Or multiple calls?**

Comment: No, you're making a call for each query, plus the start transaction call, and the commit/rollback; but the database keeps track of all the changes within the transaction so that it can commit them all in one go or roll them all back

Comment: if the number of db calls matter here, your doing something wrong

Comment: Wrong Dagon - the most important question to me - is the number of db calls - I am doing nothing at ALL wrong - and the "wrong" example ... is merely that... a simple example - save your pompous negativity for someone else - and have fun shitting on everyone :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - Mark Baker : )
I appreciate it : )

Comment: If it seems like a worthy question - please post your answer and I will gladly credit you with it. Thanks again Mark : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), or Multi-Version Concurrency Control, which is a fancy way of saying that a transaction creates a temporary alternate reality where those changes are applied but until you commit the changes nobody else can see them. When committed the database merges the changes back into the main database. If you rollback it's like they never happened.

This actually makes five calls to the server, one to open the transaction, three to insert data, and one to commit.

The transaction creates an *atomic operation*, something that either succeeds or fails as a single unit, even if it's composed of five individual operations.